# How to print the output of a generator

Tags: python, generator

When I run the code I get the following output

How do I print the print the output?

```
def firstn(n):
    num=0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num=num+1


sum_of_first_n=sum(firstn(10))
print(firstn(3))
```

Comment: `print(list(firstn(3)))`

Comment: Welcome on SO. Would you mind formatting your code properly so that others can benefit from it as well?

Answer (score 2):

In general:

```
print(list(firstn(n)))
```

Be sure your generator is not infinite. If you are not sure, use something like:

```
import itertools as it

print(list(it.islice(firstn(n), 100)))
```

to print up to the first 100 elements.

Answer (score 1):

There's different ways of doing that, but basically you have to iterate through the iterator. The simplest way is probably using list comprehension:

```
print(list(firstn(3)))
```

but if you wish you could write a `for` loop to do that (and get it fx one element per line):

```
for e in firstn(3):
    print(e)
```

One should however be aware that iterating through the generator consumes it and if you don't have means of retrieving a new generator (for example if you got the generator as parameter to a function call) you would have to store the values - fx in an array:

```
l = list(firstn(3))

for e in l:
    print(e)

for e in l:
    do_something(e)
```